# How calculate: $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{ln(1+2x^2+4y^2)}{arctan(x^2+2y^2)} $?

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I calculate: $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\ln(1+2x^2+4y^2)}{\arctan(x^2+2y^2)} $? Is there any certain path that is recommended to go through? I tried to use the inequality: $\ln(1+x) \leq x$ and got that:

$ \frac{\ln(1+2x^2+4y^2)}{\arctan(x^2+2y^2)}$ $\leq$  $ \frac{2x^2+4y^2}{\arctan(x^2+2y^2)} = \frac{2(x^2+2y^2)}{\arctan(x^2+2y^2)}. $

I got stuck here. Is there any trigonometric equation that could be helpful here? Because substituting $(0,0)$ in the $\arctan$ below is dangerous since it gives $0$, and the description is undefined. any suggestions ?

Comment: Assuming the limit actually exists, you can choose the path with $y=0$ and then calculate $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac{\ln(1+2x^2)}{\operatorname{arctan}(x^2)}}$ via L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: okay, I did what u told me, I get that the limit is zero. is that right ?

Comment: No, I get $2$ (and wolfram alpha agrees).

Comment: Whoops, my bad, calculating mistake. thanks :)

Comment: @Hayden so its legal for me to take any path I want by assuming negatively that the limit does exist? or do I need to take second path and see that it really gives the same result ?

Comment: No, to choose an arbitrary path to compute with, you need that the limit exists (since by definition the limit exists so long as it doesn't matter what path you take).  Taking the path $y=0$ (or $x=0$, or whatever) and getting a limit doesn't imply that actually is the solution to the original question because it hasn't been shown that a limit exists.  For this, use Hagen's solution.

Comment: But how do I use this quality when I have two variables ($x$ and $y$)?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I edited. If u want me to use taylor's expansion I know how to do this when I have one variable. not two.

Comment: I think one easier non rigorous way is simply to replace the whole $x^2+2y^2$ with a $h$ that tends to $0$. It easily gives the limit as 2.

Comment: yeah, I think that too. and I hope its a legal action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\ln(1+t)=t+O(t^2)$ and $\arctan t=t+O(t^2)$ as $t\to 0$.

Comment: But how do I use this quality when I have to variables ?